# Как хранить в React | Redux информацию о залогиненом пользователе?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Где в приложении на React хранить информацию о залогиненом пользователе?
На данный момент сохраняю в local storage, но не знаю правильно ли это

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно, отдаёте JSON клиенту в зашифрованном виде, получится токен который можно записать в localStorage, достаёте из localStorage, декодируете и получается ваш JSON с данными пользователя.

Почитайте более подробнее о [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Спасибо, а в каком виде мне передавать логин и пароль на сервер для авторизации?

Comment: @play0rdie в виде { login: "play0rdie", pass: "pass123" }

Comment: Оуу нуу, сохранять на стороне фронта пароль - не есть хорошо)

Comment: JWT - это в большинстве случаев не шифрование JSON, а его подписывание. То есть кто-либо может его прочесть, но изменить - не может. То есть технически может изменить, но тогда подпись не будет подходить и токен будет невалидным.

Советую сохранять в JWT только id юзера, этого должно хватить (ну и срок действия токена, само собой)

Comment: @ДавидМанжула никто и не предлагал хранить пароль на стороне фронта, перечитайте внимательно - там спрашивали в каком формате его на сервер передавать в процессе получения jwt

Comment: @PashaPash, прошу прощения, зря быканул

Answer (score 0):

когда с сервака придет токен (jwt) с данными о пользователе (без пароля), его следует поместить в куки. Хранение данных в куки файлах более безопаснее и надежнее. Можешь либу чекнуть по типу js-cookie, которая упрощает работу с ними